# Make discord js bot make a file with code/txt in it

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm wondering I have an eval command and sometimes the output text is to long I'm wondering how do i make the output go into a downloadable file that the bot makes.

Here is the eval code https://hastebin.com/etisujoneq.js can you tell me how to do it/add it and can you give me the code in general if i ever wanted to use it again.

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");



module.exports.run = async (client,message,args) => {
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "BanBot");
    if(message.member.roles.has(role.id)) return message.channel.send("Can not use this commnad!");
    var kitty = message.guild.members.find("id", "131417543888863232");
    if (message.member !== kitty)return message.channel.send("**Hey, `" + message.author.username + "` You Can't use eval only spoodercraft can!**");

const clean = text => {
  if (typeof(text) === "string")
    return text.replace(/`/g, "`" + String.fromCharCode(8203)).replace(/@/g, "@" + String.fromCharCode(8203));
  else
      return text;
}
//
if(!message.member.hasPermission("VIEW_AUDIT_LOG")) return message.channel.send("No permissions!");
//


    try{
      const code = args.join(" ");
      let evaled = eval(code);

      if (typeof evaled !== "string"){
        evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
      }

    if (evaled.includes(client.token)){
        evaled = evaled.replace(client.token, "THATS MY PRIVESSEESEES NO! AND I MEAN NO! \n\ YOU GET I WILL CALL THE COPS ");

        if (evaled.includes(client.token)){
            evaled = evaled.replace(client.token, "THATS MY PRIVESSEESEES NO! AND I MEAN NO! \n\ YOU GET I WILL CALL THE COPS ");
        }   
    }

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField(`Input`, "***```" + code + "```***", true)
    .addField(`Output`, `\`\`\`python\n${evaled}\`\`\``,)
    .setColor("#cb36ed")//
    .setTimestamp()



message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {msg.delete(25000)});

    } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send('``Error``\n ```'+ clean(err) +'```').then(msg => {msg.delete(25000)});
    }    
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "eval"
}
````

I have looked at the discord.js and looked it up alot but i have no idea.

thank you for helping me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `<string>.length` is greater than 2000 (or a little less).

**I feel a better way to do this is by having it create a hastebin as you can instead send the hastebin link, which would save you time.**

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/hastebin-gen to create the hastebin and then use the returned r variable as the link.

**Pseudo Code**

```
if(<string>.length > 2000) {
  hastebin(<code>, "js").then(function(r){
    return message.channel.send(r)
  })
}
```